# i read it on jon skeet blog and now i want to know the answer?

Tags: c#, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)
>   [Floating point comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison)

[Computers are meant to be good at arithmetic, aren't they? Why does this print "False"?](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html)

```
double d1 = 1.000001;
double d2 = 0.000001;
Console.WriteLine((d1-d2)==1.0);
```

or there result will be different in c sharp or java

Comment: This is the standard floating-point question.  Start with wikipedia.  Read that.  Then search here for the tag [floating-point].  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point.  Then.  After reading all that, please update your question so it's not a duplicate of 100's of others.

Comment: Here is the answer page for the teasers: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers-answers.html

Comment: Did you read the answers page, which has a link to my article on floating point?

Comment: See also http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg%5Fgoldberg.html "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"

Comment: @Jon sorry i miss that link sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think result may vary depending on which processor and which language you're using.
This because float numbers (in general) are stored with a number of bits that try to represent that fractional number, but there can be some (very little) difference.
So when you do `(d1-d2)` you probably get a number really close to 1.0, but not exactly 1.0!!