# Why is this floating point comparison true?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison)

When I run the code below I get the following output:

Output : if

Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float a = 0.7;
    if(a<0.7)
    {
        printf("if");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Else");
    }
}
```

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @downvoter   dont be panic just by asking same question by new user ...close such questan as duplicate but dont downvote it

Comment: This an applet which illustrates the internal working a bit better: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating points are not stored in precise format. Most likely, your platform interprets

```
float a = 0.7;
```

as

```
float a = 0.69999....;
```

This is because of the internal representation of floating points on your platform. The [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) provided by Daniel should get you started.

Comment: this still doesn't answer why a < 0.7 (see link in the comments)

Answer (score 3):

Your program compares the `double` representation of `0.7` (which is what the compiler produces when you write `0.7` in your program) with a `float` representation of `0.7` (which is what variable `a` contains). The two are not the same, and it just happens that the `double` one is slightly larger.

EDIT: `(float)0.7` can be represented compactly in hexadecimal notation. It is `0x1.666666p-1`. `0.7` as a `double` constant is `0x1.6666666666666p-1`, so it **is** slightly larger.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to accuracy issues in floating point representation on a computer. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).