# Unexpected floating point comparisons

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define k 0.7
#define p 0.5
int main()
{
    float a=k,b=p;
    double aa=k;
    if(a<k)
    {
         if(b<p) printf("2 is right");    
         else      printf("1 is right");
    }
    else printf("0 is right");
    printf("\n");
    if(a>k)
    {
         if(b<p) printf("2 is right");    
         else      printf("1 is right");
    }
    else printf("0 is right");
    return 0;
}
```

Consider this as part II of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison) question, here the understanding was that the double precision values of floating point constants (doubles when represented as numeric constants) was lost when it was converted to their corresponding floating point values. The exceptional values were X.5 and X.0. But I observed the following results:

```
Input           Output
K=0.1 to 0.4        0 is right
                    1 is right

K=0.5               0 is right
                    1 is right

K=0.6               0 is right
                    1 is right

K=0.7               1 is right
                    0 is right

K=0.8               0 is right
                    1 is right

K=0.9               1 is right
                    0 is right

K=8.4               1 is right
                    0 is right
```

Why is this queer behavior? How come only few floating point values are displaying this property? Can't we assume that `float` precision values are *always less* than `double` precision values?? How do we explain this behavior?

Comment: `a` is always equal to `k` in your example. Where is the input coming into play?

Comment: Sometimes casting a `double` to `float` yields a smaller value, sometimes a larger one, occasionally the value is the same. What's the problem?

Comment: @0A0D really?? then in all cases i should have `0 is right` as answer. See properly before you downvote

Comment: @sasidhar: `float a = k;`... where is `a` changed before `if (a<k)` ? I downvoted because its a crappy question.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is too ambiguous, right? Isn't there a way to predict the output? When someone asks me such a question should i answer `it depends!!`??

Comment: @0A0D `a` is not changed before `if(a<k)` dear, but the double precision constant `k` is cast to floating precision `a` and again compared with a double precision `k` its not crappy because you miss a concept

Comment: @sasidhar: You say "Input 0.1 to 0.4" - where are you exercising that? This question is not clear and is too ambiguous. No one is jumping on answering it because we are having trouble trying to figure out what exactly is your question.

Comment: @sasidhar It depends on the binary expansion of the number. Casting from `double` to `float` reduces the precision from 53 to 24 bits. If the 25-th bit is 0, it truncates (rounds towards zero), if it's 1, it rounds away from zero, unless the 25-th bit is the last 1-bit, then it rounds so that the 24-th bit is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't we assume that `float` precision values are always less than `double` precision values??

Not really, they may both have the same precision. You can assume that the range and precision of `double` is not smaller than that of `float`.

But, for all practical purposes, it's a profitable bet that `double` has 53 bits of precision and `float` has 24. And that `double` has 11-bit exponents, `float` 8-bit.

So, disregarding exotic architectures, `float` has less precision and a smaller range than `double`, every `float` value is representable as a `double`, but not vice versa. So casting from `float` to `double` is value-preserving, but casting from `double` to `float` will change all values needing more than 24 bits of precision.

The cast is generally performed (for values in the `float` range) by rounding the significand of the `double` value to 24 bits of precision in the following way:

- if the 25<sup>th</sup> most significant bit of the significand is 0, the significand is truncated (the value is rounded towards zero)
- if the 25<sup>th</sup> most significant bit is 1, and not all bits of lower significance are 0, the value is rounded away from zero (the significand is truncated and then the value of the lest significant bit is added)
- otherwise, the significand is rounded so tat the 24<sup>th</sup> most significant bit is zero, that rounds away from zero in half the cases and towards zero in half.

You cannot predict if casting a `double` to `float` increases or decreases the value by looking at the decimal expansion, except in the few cases where you can see that the value will be unchanged. It's the binary expansion that matters.