# Dividing using 10 gives wrong precision

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

My intention is to round a value but it gives wrong output

```
      float travellingEmptyDist = 2.05; 
travellingEmptyDist = round(travellingEmptyDist * 10); // gives value 21.0
travellingEmptyDist = travellingEmptyDist/ 10.0; // gives wrong value 2.09999, expecting 2.1
```

Is there any way to rectify it

Comment: *sigh* http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Someone should at least point out that `travellingEmptyDist` is _not_ 2.05, despite what his source code says.

Comment: related question and excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635537/c-floating-point-precision

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest watching this video 
[Computerphile: Floating Points](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

It'll give you a very simple overview about why floating points inherently are imprecise without going into too much technical detail. I'm also bias because I love numberphile.

You need to ask yourself, do you really need that extra 0.00001 of precision? If you really need more precision, use a double instead of a float, but even then you'll still have rounding errors.

If you need even higher precision, you're going to have to use a 3rd party precision arithmetic library. I've never had the need for one, but [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) seems to be popular based on Google results.

Comment: Double will get you that 0.00001f, but it won't get you "true" percision. For that you need to do fixed point math: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79677/whats-the-best-way-to-do-fixed-point-math

Comment: That is why I linked to GMP