# What is the matter with printing some float values?

Tags: c

i would like to know what is my problem when i try to print some float values, for example, in this simple programme :

```
float n = 127.998 ;
printf("%f",n);
```

The execution gives : **127.998001**.

- So why i have the additional **1** back of this number ?

[image: attached image]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635537/c-floating-point-precision

Comment: Obligatory [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some values cannot be accurately stored in a floating point data type. There is no guarantee that your `float n = 127.998` will actually be stored as exactly `127.998` . For values that cannot be accurately represented in floating point types, the closest value to that is stored instead, which is what you got.