# floating point precision giving wrong output. please help in bypassing such errors

Tags: floating-point-precision

So i have got a problem with floating point variables. can someone explain? the code is given below...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    float b=3.6;
    if(b==3.6)
    {
        printf("one");
    }
    if(b<=3.6)
    {
        printf("two");
    }
    if(b>=3.6)
    {
        printf("three");
    }
    else printf("four");
}
```

**Now why is the Output "two" and "four"?** and how do i avoid such things in pprograms?

Comment: See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison)

Comment: there are already lots of duplicates about "floating point precision" here

Comment: also, avoid float unless needed, most probably in storage, normal temporary calculations should use double instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `float`s to `double`s. Try comparing them to `3.6f` instead of `3.6`

Comment: by default does it take 3.6 as double when comparing?

Comment: You might want to check this: [What's the point of the L, U and f suffixes on numeric literals?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/numeric-literal-suffixes.html)

Comment: And answering to your comment... yes, every unsuffixed literal with decimals is taken as a `double`, so it's actually promoting `b` to `double`, and making the comparison afterwards