# Can't figure out how the answer comes out to be true

Tags: c

Can't figure out how come:
`0.7 >0.7` is true.Seems to be a trick question.

```
    void main()
float a=0.7;`

if(a < 0.7)`
{
     printf("TRUE");
}   

    else
    {
         printf("FALSE");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison

Answer (score 3):

This is because variable `a` is a `float`, and the constant `0.7` is `double`. Representation of 0.7 in floating point types is not precise. When the value is converted to `float`, the result becomes slightly smaller than the `double` value. This difference could go both ways, i.e. `float` representation may become slightly greater than the corresponding `double` after the conversion.

Adding a cast will fix the problem:

```
if(a < (float)0.7) {
     printf("TRUE");
} else {
     printf("FALSE");
}
```

Comment: Maybe better: declaring `a` as `double a=0.7;` will fix it too.

Comment: @Marian Yes, that would make the two values compare equal as well.