# Float comparision

Tags: java, c

in C language

```
float a=0.1;

if(a==.1)
  printf("hello");
else
 printf("123");
```

Output is `123`

But for Java

```
float a=0.1F;

if(a==.1)
  System.out.println("hello");
else
  System.out.println("123");
```

Ans is `hello`.

Why?

Comment: read [this](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)

Comment: *Ans is hello* are you sure ? I doubt.

Comment: I executed this code on an online compiler and the output seems to be `123`

Comment: [I'm also getting `123`.](http://ideone.com/b13Xu7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714) [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Those links aren't actually relevant here. The reported behavior would not be the result of floating point rounding error or any of the usual sources of confusion with floating point numbers.

Comment: it's a bug in the C compiler, or your platform has `sizeof(double) == sizeof(float)`

Comment: Did you mean to use 0.1F in all four cases?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. On my gcc it prints 123.

Comment: online compiler shows 123 but in my eclipse, it shows hello.
May be it depends on compiler

Answer (score 2):

Here comparison by `==` first converts `float` to `double` and than compares both value.

```
float real = 0.1f;
double real2 = real;
System.out.println(real2);
```

***OUTPUT***

```
0.10000000149011612
```

Now you can see when you convert `float` to `double` for value `0.1` you will not get the exact value here. Here system will convert your `float` value to `double` with *extra* precision in data.

Same thing happens here when you write `if(a==.1)` your `a` will be converted to something like `0.10000000149011612` and than compares with `0.1` which is already `double` and has exact value `0.1` and so it result to `false` and must print `123` and not `hello` that I am sure about.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges. In the Java case, you should be using

```
if (a == 0.1F)
```

Comment: Don't both code snippets use a double literal in the `if`?

Comment: I think the problem here is that he expects the same (`123`) but is getting `hello`

Comment: @user2357112 Of course, but the point is that the literals mean different things in the two languages, as already exhibited by the declarations.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta Of course it is. Your point?

Comment: @EJP: No, the literals mean the same thing (or at least, they mean the same thing on platforms where a C double is IEEE 754 binary64). There's a discrepancy earlier in the code, where one version assigns `float a=0.1;` and one assigns `float a=0.1F;`, but there's no apples-and-oranges problem in the `if` itself.

Comment: My point is that he's getting the wrong output for a correct program. If he is using `if (a == 0.1)` then it should return `false` since `0.1` is `double`, but it is returning `true` in his case.

Comment: Actually, I think we might be reading the question differently. I see it as an issue of the float/double comparison working differently in differently languages. You might be interpreting it a different way.